# Colocar los archivos estáticos en otra unidad de disco de una aplicación web con asp-net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Estoy realizando una aplicación web con asp-net core 5 y necesito que una carpeta de los archivos estáticos este fuera de la carpeta wwwroot, concretamente en la unidad D: del servidor IIS. Esta carpeta sería algo así: `D:\Cms`.

En el archivo **`appsettings.json`** tengo esta configuración:

```
{
  "Cms": {
    "unidadDisco": "D:\\",
    "rutaCms": "D:\\Cms",
    "linkCms": "/Cms"
  }
  }
}
```

Y en el archivo **`Startup.cs`** tengo esta otra configuración:

```
// Archivos estáticos en ASP.NET Core
string rutaCms = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Cms:rutaCms");// C:\\Cms ó D:\\Cms

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(rutaCms),
    RequestPath = "/Cms",
});

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

Con esta configuración si la carpeta Cms la coloco en la unidad C: (`C:\Cms`) el servidor IIS si accede a los archivos estáticos, pero si la cambio a la unidad D: (D:\Cms) no accede a los archivos estáticos y el IIS me da un **error 401**.

Pero, si ejecuto esta aplicación desde Visual Studio me funciona bien en ambos casos, lo cual no se si el problema me lo está dando el servidor IIS o el servidor IIS necesita alguna configuración.

Todo esto viene porque necesito liberar espacio en la unidad C: del servidor y tener la opción de poder cambiar esta carpeta a la ubicación que se necesite.

Otra cosa curiosa es que si al publicar la aplicación al servidor, tengo configurada la carpeta Cms a la unidad D: y elimino la carpeta de la unidad C: el servidor me da un error 500.30

De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: IIS tiene permisos de leer el directorio? Averigua si el usuario IIS_IUSRS tiene permisos de lectura y/o escritura en el directorio desde donde estás sirviendo las imágenes

Comment: El usuario IIS_IUSRS si tiene permisos Control total.

Comment: Sí usas IIX Exprees para debug, se debe vaidar que el usuario que lanza la app también tenga permisos, el enlace símbólico soporta incluso operaciones de redes, estoy replicando con el File Provider porque teoricamente debe funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución para el problema que plantee, que ha consistido en crear un enlace simbólico desde c:\Cms ha D:\Cms. Y con esto he conseguido que funcione.

mklink /D C:\Cms D:\Cms

Un saludo

César